# Haskell#concat Implementation

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

Here's how I implemented `concat` - flattens a list of lists into just a list of elements.

```
concat' :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat' ys = foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ x) [] ys
```

Is it a problem that I'm using the `++` function?

What's a better way to write this?

Answer (score 2):

You could eta-contract the definition in two places: `\acc x -> acc ++ x` is the eta-expanded version of `(++)` and `concat' ys = (...) ys` is the eta-expanded version of `concat' = (...)`. So that would take you to:

```
concat' :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat' = foldl (++) []
```

Now, in that case it turns out that it's better to use `foldr` rather than `foldl` and there is a [good write-up about concat on the haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Stack_overflow).